# Why is camera view not visible in layout tab

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I have scene like this, and if I press the view camera (numpad 0), it displays an empty screen. Please any idea how to solve it? It works in the shading tab, but not in the layout. In the layout, it works in an empty new project. I am not sure how I broke it.

I tried to modify clip start and end

[image: Normal view]
[image: Broken view]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: here it is https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/iuspqm6bfnt252iqqr7gy/camera-issue.blend?rlkey=bg1yzznxxp1llh9mr4dhdoool&dl=0  I just simplified with cube

Comment: Look through the Camera then press Home key or go to View>Cameras>Frame Camera Bounds.  This will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you! It helped :D ... Blender is so great, but sometimes those things are so hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution in Blenderartists, quit Blender, reopen, and when you open the file, open the options panel and disable *Load UI*, the problem will be fixed (you could also copy-paste or append from a file to another), but it doesn't explain what happened:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have not tried it. It was solved by Rumen's solution via View>Cameras>Frame Camera Bounds.

Comment: Yes, you're right, still don't know what happened though